# Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@33909752]-1 ERROR An exception occurred

Tags: java, log4j, guice, bukkit

i use guice in my bukkit plugin and i got that error:
Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@33909752]-1 ERROR An exception occurred
2022-07-19 13:02:17,704 Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@33909752]-1 ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender File com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed.

Anyone knows how fix this?

```
[13:02:17 INFO]: [CWCasino] Enabling CWCasino v1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
2022-07-19 13:02:17,704 Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@33909752]-1 ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender File com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2217)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4154)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4158)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:5147)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:5153)
at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements.forType(StackTraceElements.java:83)
at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatSource(Errors.java:803)
at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatSource(Errors.java:785)
at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.format(Errors.java:584)
at com.google.inject.ConfigurationException.getMessage(ConfigurationException.java:72)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:108)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEvent.getThrownProxy(RingBufferLogEvent.java:335)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.format(ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.java:63)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternFormatter.format(PatternFormatter.java:44)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$PatternSelectorSerializer.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:561)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toText(PatternLayout.java:241)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.encode(PatternLayout.java:226)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.encode(PatternLayout.java:60)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.directEncodeEvent(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:197)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:190)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:181)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingRandomAccessFileAppender.append(RollingRandomAccessFileAppender.java:243)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:542)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:500)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:483)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:471)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:98)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.actualAsyncLog(AsyncLogger.java:488)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEvent.execute(RingBufferLogEvent.java:156)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventHandler.onEvent(RingBufferLogEventHandler.java:51)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventHandler.onEvent(RingBufferLogEventHandler.java:29)
at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.processEvents(BatchEventProcessor.java:168)
at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:125)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:690)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:319)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:251)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:234)
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:120)
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements$1.load(StackTraceElements.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements$1.load(StackTraceElements.java:43)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3716)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2424)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2298)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2211)
... 38 more

2022-07-19 13:02:17,708 Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@33909752]-1 ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender TerminalConsole com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2217)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4154)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4158)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:5147)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:5153)
at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements.forType(StackTraceElements.java:83)
at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatSource(Errors.java:803)
at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatSource(Errors.java:785)
at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.format(Errors.java:584)
at com.google.inject.ConfigurationException.getMessage(ConfigurationException.java:72)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:108)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEvent.getThrownProxy(RingBufferLogEvent.java:335)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.format(ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.java:63)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternFormatter.format(PatternFormatter.java:44)
at net.minecrell.terminalconsole.HighlightErrorConverter.format(HighlightErrorConverter.java:92)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternFormatter.format(PatternFormatter.java:44)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$PatternSelectorSerializer.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:561)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$PatternSelectorSerializer.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:552)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:217)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:60)
at net.minecrell.terminalconsole.TerminalConsoleAppender.append(TerminalConsoleAppender.java:256)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:542)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:500)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:483)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:471)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:98)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.actualAsyncLog(AsyncLogger.java:488)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEvent.execute(RingBufferLogEvent.java:156)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventHandler.onEvent(RingBufferLogEventHandler.java:51)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventHandler.onEvent(RingBufferLogEventHandler.java:29)
at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.processEvents(BatchEventProcessor.java:168)
at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:125)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:690)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:319)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:251)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:234)
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:120)
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements$1.load(StackTraceElements.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements$1.load(StackTraceElements.java:43)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3716)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2424)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2298)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2211)
... 37 more

[13:02:17 INFO]: [CWCasino] Disabling CWCasino v1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 0):

i forgot to add Module into Injector.

[add module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEz0a.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).